# Closed - form expression for the finite sum $\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{\pi\, k}{n}+\frac{\pi }{2 \ n}\right)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Is there a closed - 
 form expression for the finite sum on the secant function :  $$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{\pi \, k}{n}+\frac{\pi }{2\,n}\right)$$
as a function of n?

**Motivation:**

The sum is part of a more elaborated solution of [Eric Naslund](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491241/closed-form-for-int-infty-infty-operatornamesechx-operatornamesech) of the integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \text{sech}(z)\,\text{sech}(n\,z) \, dz = \frac{\pi}{2\,
n} \sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{\pi\, k}{n}+\frac{\pi }{2\,n}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sec \left(\frac{\pi\, n}{2}\right)$$

which holds for any even number n.

**Attempt at a solution:**

There are some interesting papers, [WEN CHANG CHU](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222240349_Summations_on_trigonometric_functions), [Djurdje Cvijovic, H.M. Srivastava](https://www.academia.edu/4280157/Summation_of_a_family_of_finite_secant_sums) and [HONGWEI CHEN](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222240349_Summations_on_trigonometric_functions), considering the summation of finite secant sums.

Investigations of the first bibliographical reference lead to the closed form expression for the similar finite sum:

$$\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \sec \left(2 \left(\frac{\pi\,k}{n}+y\right)\right)=\frac{2\,n \,\sin \left(\frac{\pi\,n}{4}\right) \,\cos \left(\frac{n\,y}{2}\right)}{\cos
(n\,y)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi\,n}{2}\right)}+\sec (y)$$

with $y = \frac{1}{2\,n}$, which can be further investigated by:

$$\sec (2\,z) = \frac{\sec ^2(z)}{2-\sec ^2(z)}$$

and

$$\sec (\frac{z}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\cos (z)+1}} (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{\pi +\Re(z)}{2 \pi }\right\rfloor } \left(1-\left((-1)^{\left\lfloor -\frac{\pi +\Re(z)}{2 \pi }\right\rfloor
+\left\lfloor \frac{\pi +\Re(z)}{2 \pi }\right\rfloor }+1\right) \theta (-\Im(z))\right)
$$
where $\Theta$ is the "unitstep" - function.

In case of the last bibliographical reference, **the main difference to the sum above** is, that [HONGWEI CHEN], deals only with higher powers of a similar sum - but without that "factor 2" - e.g.

$$S_{2 n}(\text{q})\text{:=}\sum _{p = 0\,\text{;}\,p\neq \frac{q}{2}  (\text{q is even})}^{q-1} \sec ^{2\, n}\left(\frac{\pi\,  p}{q}\right)$$

Another attempt at a solution is to write the sum as a "q-series" [Dieckmann](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#q-Series).

**EDIT**

A new approach is to split the sum e.g. 
for $n=4,8,12,...$ [Claude Leibovici]

$$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{\pi  (2\,k+1)}{2\,n}\right)=2 \sum _{l=0}^{\frac{n}{4}-1} (-1)^l \sec \left(\frac{\pi \, (2\,l+1)}{2\,n}\right)-2
\sum _{l=0}^{\frac{n}{4}-1} (-1)^l \csc \left(\frac{\pi\,  (2\,l+1)}{2\,n}\right)$$

The summary of the preliminary work give some evidence that a closed - 
 form expression exists:

The finite sum can be simplified to:

$$S_{n}=\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{\pi\,k}{n}+\frac{\pi }{2\,n}\right)=2 \,\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \sec \left(\frac{2\,\pi\,k}{n}+\frac{\pi}{2\,n}\right)$$

For the proof one has to split the sum in even and odd "k's".

From expressions of the first bibliographical reference and the help of [Dieckmann](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#q-Series) the following identity can be proven:

$$W_{n}=\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\cos \left(\frac{2\, \pi\,  k}{n}\right)+z}=\frac{ n \,\cot \left(\frac{n}{4}\, \left(2\, \sin^{-1}(z)+\pi \right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}+\frac{1}{z+1}$$

From the proof of the main result of [HONGWEI CHEN] one derive the further identity:

$$V_{n}=\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\cos \left(\frac{\pi \, k}{n}\right)+z}=\frac{z}{z^2-1}-\frac{n \cot \left(n \cos ^{-1}(z)\right)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$

Now we split the finite sum $W_{n}$ for even numbers n:

$$W_{n}=\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} \frac{1}{\cos \left(\frac{2 \,\pi \, k}{n}\right)+z}+\sum _{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \frac{1}{\cos \left(\frac{2\,\pi \,k}{n}\right)+z}$$

We express the first sum of $W_{n}$ by $V_{n}$ and solve for the last sum. This leads to:

$$S_{z,w,n}=2 \sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{z-\cos \left(\frac{\pi \, k}{n}+\frac{\pi}{w\,n}\right)}$$

For $w=1$ we have:

$$S_{z,1,n}=\frac{2\, n \,\left(\cot \left(n \cos ^{-1}(z)\right)+2\, \cot \left(\frac{1}{2} \,n \,\left(2 \,\sin ^{-1}(z)+\pi \right)\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}+\frac{2}{1-z^2}$$

The limit $\lim_{z\to 0}$ and $w=4$ gives the solution. With other words we need a general expression, dependent of $w$, with $S_{z,1,n}$ for $w=1$.

**EDIT II**

Mathematica can find a solution expressed in closed form using the q-polygamma function:

$$S_{\frac{n}{2}}=\frac{2\,n}{\pi } \left(\psi _{e^{-\frac{i\,\pi}{n}}}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{n}{2}\right)-2\, \psi _{e^{-\frac{i\,\pi }{n}}}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{n}{2}\right)+\psi_{e^{-\frac{i\,\pi }{n}}}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3\,n}{2}\right)\right)$$

where $\psi _q(z)$ is the q-polygamma function. With the function "FunctionExpand" Mathematica expands the q-polygamma function with the complex argument and one can verify the radicals of [Vepir].
Numerically the values can be optained by the well-known identity for the q-polygamma function:

$$\psi _q(x+1)=\psi _q(x)-\frac{q^x \log (q)}{1-q^x}$$

Using the identity n-times recursively, in the expression $S_{\frac{n}{2}}$, $\psi _q(x)$ for $x=\frac{1}{4}$ vanishes!

**Summary**

These results are the same!

1. $$\mathcal{I}\left( n \right)=\int_0^{\infty } \text{sech}(z)\,\text{sech}(n\,z) \, dz$$
2. $$\mathcal{I}\left( n \right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k \left(\psi \left(\frac{3 n+2k+1}{4 n}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{n+2 k+1}{4 n}\right)\right)$$
3. $$\mathcal{I}\left( n \right)=\frac{\pi}{2\,n} \sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{\pi\, k}{n}+\frac{\pi }{2\,n}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sec \left(\frac{\pi\, n}{2}\right)$$
4. $$\mathcal{I}\left( n \right)=\frac{\pi} {2 \,n} \left(\sum _{l=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(E_l\right){}^2 \left(\frac{i\, \pi }{2\, n}\right)^l}{l!}-n \,i^n\right)+\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sec \left(\frac{\pi\, n}{2}\right)$$
5. $$\mathcal{I}\left( n \right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi _{e^{-\frac{2\, i \,\pi}{n}}}\left(\frac{1-n}{4}\right)-2\, \psi _{e^{-\frac{2\, i\, \pi }{n}}}\left(\frac{1+n}{4}\right)+\psi_ {e^{-\frac{2\, i\, \pi }{n}}}\left(\frac{1}{4} (1+3 \,n)\right)\right)+  \\
   +\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sec \left(\frac{\pi\, n}{2}\right)$$
6. $$\mathcal{I}\left( n \right)=\frac{\pi}{2\,n} \left((n+1)-\sec\left(\frac{\pi }{2 \,n}\right)\left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2\, n}\right)-3\right)+\\
   + 2\, \sum _{m=-\frac{n}{4}}^{\frac{n}{4}} \cot \left(\frac{\pi \, \left(m-\frac{1}{4}\right)}{n}\right)+2 \sum_{m=-\frac{n}{2}}^{\frac{n}{2}} \frac{1}{\cot\left(\frac{\pi \, \left(m-\frac{1}{4}\right)}{n}\right)-1}\right) +\frac{1}{2} \pi  \sec \left(\frac{\pi\, n}{2}\right)$$

**"6."** follows from **"5"** and has a nice form for $n=2,6,10,\cdots$. The first term is the approximation of [Claude Leibovici].

Comment: Does the finite series solution only equate to the integral for even $n$? or Is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @JamesArathoon: You are right, the original solution from Eric Naslund was more general, he set $a = \frac{c}{d}$ and limited it to a rational number 
with at least one of c,d even. I set $a = n$, so n is even natural number. I think one can evaluate the integral also for an odd n.

Comment: For $n$  odd there are terms which are infinite in the finite sum. Do you want to restrict to $n$ even?

Comment: @Somos: Yes, I know that the finite sum is infinite for odd numbers n, therefore the solution is restricted to n even. Moreover there might be two different solutions, for $n= 4m$ and $n=4m+2$ and $m=1,2,...$ as discribed in the section "Edit". Thank you!

Comment: I haven't found a closed form. But I did find for first six values (forms in terms of nested radicals):

$$
\begin{array}{l|r}
n=2& 2 \sqrt{2} \\
n=4& -4 \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} \\
n=6& 4 \sqrt{6}-2 \sqrt{2} \\
n=8& -4 \sqrt{12-2 \sqrt{7 \sqrt{2}+10}} \\
n=10& 2 \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+4\right)-4 \sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}} \\
n=12& -4 \sqrt{-11 \sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3}-4 \sqrt{6}+26} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: @Vepir: Thank you very much for the interest. The finite sum gives that nested radicals, this can be investigate with the q-series, coming up with the QPolygamma-function. Since the argument is complex, I did not know, how to deal with it, but Mathematica simplifies it in the that radicals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the sequence of numbers for all positive even integer $n$
$$ a_n := \sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{\pi \, k}{n}+\frac{\pi }{2\,n}\right). \tag{1} $$
The sequence has an [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) power series expansion in 
powers of $\,1/n\,$
$$ a_n \sim -n\,i^n + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{E_k^2}{k!}
\left(\frac{\pi\, i}{2\, n}\right)^k. \tag{2} $$
All terms with odd $\,k\,$ in the summation
are zero since the Euler number $\,E_k=0.\,$ The series is
**asymptotic** so the partial sums start to converge but
after a certain point they diverge to infinity. However,
the Wikipedia article on [divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) lists several methods of summing
divergent series and one or more of them may be of use here.

Note that Euler numbers are [OEIS sequence A122045](https://oeis.org/A122045) with e.g.f. $\text{sech}(x),\,$ but the sequence of its squares $\,E_k^2\,$
is **not** in OEIS and so it is unlikely for its
e.g.f. to have a simple closed form, but it still may be possible.
The Wikipedia article [1-1+2-6+24-120+...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_1_%2B_2_%E2%88%92_6_%2B_24_%E2%88%92_120_%2B_...) gives hope that this may be the case.

The Wolfram language code I used for exploring $q$-digamma based on the
expression of the OP.

```
ClearAll[ank, a, ax, qd, f];
ank[n_,k_] := (-1)^k Sec[Pi k/n + Pi/2/n];
a[n_?EvenQ] := a[n] = Sum[ ank[n, k], {k, 0, n-1}];
ax[n_, t_] := -n I^n + Sum[ EulerE[k]^2 (I Pi/2/n)^k/k!, {k, 0, 2*t}];
qd[z_, q_] := QPolyGamma[z, q]; (* q-digamma = psi_q(z) *)
f[n_, q_:0] := Module[{q1 = If[q==0, Exp[2 Pi I/n], q]},
    n/Pi (qd[(1-n)/4, q1] - 2 qd[(1+n)/4, q1] + qd[(1+3n)/4, q1])];
```

Notice that evaluating the $q$-digamma in `f[n]` at roots of unity
blows up and Mathematica will leave it unevaluated. You can verify
this by evaluating `f[n,Exp[2 Pi I/n]x]` where $x$ is **close** to $1$. 
Also, notice that `f[n]//FunctionExpand//N` does **not** evaluate to
a numerical value for even integer values of $\,n\ge12.\,$

Comment: Since $E_{2n}\sim \frac{ 4^{n+1}(2n)!}{\pi^{2n+1}}$  the series  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{E_k^2}{k!}x^k$ has zero radius of convergence.

Comment: @Somos: I don't understand the conclusion of your interesting power series: e.g. 
[mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) you find: "Certain classes...expressed in closed..."
With Mathematica I find: See: EDIT II

Comment: @stocha. Thanks for your comment. The q-digamma expressions in your question don't evaluate when I tried it with Mathematica. Have you tried to evaluate them for numerical values of $n$?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your comment. I now see that the series is only asymptotic just like the series for $n!$ in powers of $1/n$.

Comment: Try $\frac{2 n \left(\text{QPolyGamma}\left[0,\frac{1}{w}-\frac{n}{2},e^{-\frac{i \pi }{n}}\right]-2 \text{QPolyGamma}\left[0,\frac{1}{w}+\frac{n}{2},e^{-\frac{i\pi }{n}}\right]+\text{QPolyGamma}\left[0,\frac{1}{w}+\frac{3 n}{2},e^{-\frac{i \pi }{n}}\right]\right)}{\pi }$ for w =4. Then do "FunctionExpand" to produce the radicals. For n=1 the result is 2.82843

Comment: @Somos: It would be great, if you could explain me how to deal with the complex valued q-polygamma function. Interesting is also the case w=1, where we get "1" - see EDIT. This means we have a new identity

Comment: @stocha I think that $q$-polygamma is complicated. There is probably a better answer which I don't know about yet.

Comment: @Somos: I finally understand how Mathematica could calculate the nested radicals. He probably uses an identity to recursively reduce n.

Comment: @Somos: If you have some time, please take a look at the "summary". Maybe you get an idea later on. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For an *approximation*, it seems that for $n=2,6,10,\cdots$
$$S_n=\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{(2   k+1)\pi }{2 n}\right)\sim 1+n$$ and that for  $n=4,8,12,\cdots$
$$S_n=\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \sec \left(\frac{(2   k+1)\pi }{2 n}\right)\sim 1-n$$

**For illustration**

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & 1+n & S_n\\
 2 & 3 & 2.82843 \\
 6 & 7 & 6.96953 \\
 10 & 11 & 10.9882 \\
 14 & 15 & 14.9939 \\
 18 & 19 & 18.9963 \\
 22 & 23 & 22.9975
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & 1-n & S_n\\
 4 & -3 & -3.06147 \\
 8 & -7 & -7.01795 \\
 12 & -11 & -11.0083 \\
 16 & -15 & -15.0047 \\
 20 & -19 & -19.0030 \\
 24 & -23 & -23.0021
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, very interesting! I checked this, it seems that e.g.: $\lim_{m\to \infty } \, \left(S_{4 m+2}-\left(4 m+3\right)\right)=0$

Comment: @stocha. It does not seem. This is true : for $m=100$, your expression is  $-7.64 \times 10^{-6}$ and for $m=1000$ it is  $-7.70 \times 10^{-8}$ and for $m=10000$ it is  $-7.66 \times 10^{-10}$

Comment: I have drawn the wrong conclusion, thanks!